# How can I nest my for loop to go back and forward in a tab control page in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net

```
 private void nextbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
 { 
           int i = 1, j = 13;
             for (j = 13; j > i; --j) 
                 for (i = 1; i < 13; ++i)

                     tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[j+i]; 


 }
```

Let's say we have a TabControl holding 13 tabpages and we added a button outside the tabcontrol labeld "Next" and "Back"... 
The code above is coded for the "Next" button, which will take me to the next tabpage in the tabcontrol. I'm trying to find a way to make this happen, but my code is not correct, please any help?

Comment: forget about loops, check that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1323470/how-do-i-tell-which-tab-you-are-moving-from-to-in-a-winforms-tab-control

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
   if (tabControl1.SelectedIndex < tabControl1.TabCount)
        tabControl1.SelectedIndex++;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should define currentTabPage as a global var Int.

```
 int selected = currentTabPage;
        if (selected < 0 || i > 13)
        {
            selected = 0;
        }
        selected++;
        for (int i = selected; i < 13; i++)
        {
            tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabControl1.TabPages[i]; 
            currentTabPage =i;
        }
```

Comment: lhking, thanks for the help :) but I've used Steve Wellens' code, thanks again!

Answer (score -1):

I suggest taking off the integer J inside the for loop and deal with the "i" instead.